# ReportLab PDF, Table header repeating in first page

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am using **reportLab** library to generate pdf. Table header is repeating on the first page. I need to remove it. Other pages are working fine.
I am using `repeatRows=1` to show the header on top of each page.
PDF generation code is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dNd2MhY5wY/)
python==2.7, reportlab==2.7

[image]

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), you can pass a number or a tuple to `repeatRows`, and "_If it is a tuple it should specify which of the leading rows should be repeated; this allows for cases where the first appearance of the table has more leading rows than later split parts_". If the first appearance of your table has more leading rows than later split using a tuple will much likely solve your problem.

Comment: @MuriloSitonio First appearance of my table has no leading row.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `splitByRow=0 with repeatRows=1`

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).